# Are UK Home Office email addresses case sensitive?

Tags: uk-visa

I have this email ID for priority visa application:

Tier4priorityservice@homeoffice.gsi.gov.uk

Is this case sensitive?

Comment: Don't need to worry about it. The chances for them to reply are pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

No.
The global internet email system is not case sensitive, so at the first server the email pass by, any case is ignored (if not removed).

Comment: Right advice: proceed as if case does not matter. However, "the local-part MUST be interpreted and assigned semantics only by the host specified in the domain part of the address" in other words it can be case sensitive, but very rarely is. See this answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807909/are-email-addresses-case-sensitive

Comment: Actually, technically, the username part of email addresses **is** case-sensitive, and the domain part is case-insensitive. While many email servers treat usernames on a case-insensitive basis, it is not guaranted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807909/are-email-addresses-case-sensitive